# How to fix Permission denied on ubuntu server

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, bin

I'm trying to install and configure an open source platform on Ubuntu server by following specific guide.

I run this command on putty

> sudo -H -S -u edxapp /bin/sh -c "HOME=/edx/app/edxapp/.rbenv RBENV_ROOT=/edx/app/edxapp/.rbenv GEM_HOME=/edx/app/edxapp/.gem PATH=/edx/app/edxapp/.rbenv/bin:/edx/app/edxapp/.rbenv/shims:/edx/app/edxapp/.gem/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin GEM_ROOT=/edx/app/edxapp/.gem rbenv install 1.9.3-p374"

but an error appears

> /bin/sh: 1: rbenv: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

Try "sudo chmod" on the Folder. Change its permissions and try again.